# How to load the form and then read the code

Tags: c#, wpf

When I start the program, it first writes "Hello" then "Bye" and then the form is loaded, but I want to load the form and then the textbox writes it.

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "Hello";
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    TextBox1.Text = "Bye";
}
```

Comment: Please clarify, is WindowsForms or WPF. One of your tags is wfp which I think is a typo for WPF but you referece Forms in your code.

Comment: You should use `Loaded` event instead.

Answer (score 1):

If this is WPF then

```
<Window x:Class="MainForm"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Your App" Loaded="Form_Loaded">
```

C#

```
private void Form_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "Hello";
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    TextBox1.Text = "Bye";
}
```

Comment: @ASh Yea, I am just using his exact code to show how new function will work. What should be or shouldn't be is whole new discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Shown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) event:

> Occurs whenever the form is first displayed.
>
> The Shown event is only raised the first time a form is displayed;
>   subsequently minimizing, maximizing, restoring, hiding, showing, or
>   invalidating and repainting will not raise this event. For more
>   information about the order of events of a form, see Order of Events
>   in Windows Forms.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx